# Why was swapcase function added in Python's str class?

Tags: python

I was writing an article on the swapcase function of Python's str class and couldn't think of any real-world use case of this function?

What's a real-world use case of Python's swapcase function?

Has anyone ever used swapcase function in a real-world project?

[image]

Comment: Was added? It has been there since Python 1.

Comment: A real-world use case would be swapping upper and lower case letters. Not sure what you'd expect as an example.

Comment: @0stone0 OP is obviously asking when you would ever need this (apart from homework I guess).

Comment: Here is [one example](https://github.com/3-manifolds/SnapPy/blob/2ede2d0c9e82fbc80b0d7afc93cee10ea81cbec6/python/snap/nsagetools.py) I found on github.

Comment: A quick example I can think of; if someones enters a password with CAPSLOCK on, you can use `swapcase` to change the string as if CAPSLOCK was never on.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The question where swapcase is used in actual projects is not opinion based, it can be answered with links.

Comment: I've used it for [Alchemical Reduction](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/5) - [here](https://github.com/wimglenn/advent-of-code-wim/blob/cb949bf9eed64bdbae634aaf6259d8f447e17819/aoc_wim/aoc2018/q05.py#L8-L17).

Comment: @0stone0 It's better to use lower() in case of CAPSLOCK on, isn't it?

Comment: Great! That could be one example.

Comment: @YuvrajSinghJadon on windows, CAPS + Shift gives lower-case letters. So if you want to type uppercase, but had CAPS on by accident, you'll right lower-case letters.

Comment: Glad it helped. I'll post it as an answer if you'd like and the questions get re-opened.

Comment: The capslock button on your keyboard is stuck on, so you write a global keyboard hook in python that uses `swapcase` to invert whatever you type. It then injects the modified events back into the active window.